# How to remove the "SecurityPlugin" device admin app?

Tags: uninstallation, device-administrator

I don't know how I installed the below application to my phone and now I can't remove it or uninstall it. The app is called "SecurityPlugin".

[image]

Anyone can help?

Comment: Wecome to Android Enthusiasts! It must have been installed with one of your app. You need to find that particularapp, and remove Security Plugin from within that particular app.